# Dismiss Presented View Controller from Another View in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, navigation, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a **ViewController**  named **A**. it contains a button to present a new **ViewController** named `LinkedInWebVC`.
now, I want to dismiss a `LinkedInWebVC` from **A**.

### my code is as follow:

```
-(IBAction)button_tap:(id)sender
{
_loginWebViewController = [[LinkedInWebVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"LinkedInWebVC" bundle:nil];
    
    [self presentViewController:_loginWebViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:^{
                         [self.oauth1Controller loginWithWebView:_loginWebViewController.webView completion:^(NSDictionary *oauthTokens, NSError *error) {
                             if (!error) {
                                 // Store your tokens for authenticating your later requests, consider storing the tokens in the Keychain
                                 self.oauthToken = oauthTokens[@"oauth_token"];
                                 self.oauthTokenSecret = oauthTokens[@"oauth_token_secret"];
                                 
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 NSLog(@"Error authenticating: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                             }
             
                             [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
                                 self.oauth1Controller = nil;
                             }]; `*****Problem is here, not dismiss LinkedInWebVC*****`
                         }];
                     }];

}
```

Comment: You can use delegate to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling on `self` try to call dismiss method on `_loginWebViewController`

```
 [_loginWebViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
                                 self.oauth1Controller = nil;
                             }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion..]
```

to

```
[_loginWebViewController dismiss]
```

Because this "self" is presentingViewController.

Answer (score 1):

*Follow this simple steps to call a view from secondView controller and dismiss it from mainView Controller and to call third view controller immediately*

Step 1: Create a .h file that contains protocol.

```
//  ViewDelegate.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)DismissSecondView;
@end
```

Step 2: Inherit the delegate as below in viewController.h file

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
#import "ViewDelegate.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<ViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *FirstView;

-(void)PresentThirdView;
@end
```

Step 3: Implement the method in ViewController.m file

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)ChangeViewAction:(id)sender {
  SecondViewController * vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
  vc.delegate = self;//important step
  [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)DismissSecondView{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  [self PresentThirdView];
}
-(void)PresentThirdView{
  ThirdViewController * tvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ThirdViewController"];
  [self presentViewController:tvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Step 4: Assign the property for the delegate in SecondViewController.h file

```
//  SecondViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#include "ViewDelegate.h"


@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ViewDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Step 5: Call the method within an action in SeconViewController.m
//  SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
}
- (IBAction)DismissAction:(id)sender {
  [self.delegate DismissSecondView]; //calling DismissSecondView Method
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```